Can't find PGRasterConfig
When I shall create a PGRasterReader I must first create a PGRasterConfig, but I can't Import this class. PGRasterReader is imported ok. Isn't PGRasterConfig included in gt-postgis-raster?
public PGRasterReader​(PGRasterConfig config,
                  PGRasterFormat format,
                  Hints hints)
           throws IOException


PGRasterConfig is package private which I suspect means that constructor shouldn't be public either.
I managed to create a config with this code, which gives me a reasonable answer.
    PGRasterFactory fac = new PGRasterFactory();
    PGRasterFormat r = fac.createFormat();
    String config = "<pgraster>" +
            "        <name>Ian</name>" +
            "        <database> \n" +
            "          <host>localhost</host>\n" +
            "          <port>5432</port>" +
            "          <name>ian</name>" +
            "          <user>ian</user>" +
            "          <passwd>ianian</passwd>" +
            "        </database>\n" +
            "        <raster>\n" +
            "          <table>dsm-2m</table>" +
            "          <schema>rasters</schema>" +
            "        </raster>\n" +
            "        <time>" +
            "           <enabled>false</enabled>"  +
            "        </time>" +
            "      </pgraster>";

    File f = File.createTempFile("pgr", ".xml");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    fw.write(config);
    fw.close();

    PGRasterReader reader = r.getReader(f);
    if (reader==null){
        System.out.println("No reader");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = reader.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
    GeneralBounds bbox = reader.getOriginalEnvelope();
    System.out.println(""+bbox+" in "+crs);

